# How to instantiate an interface with an empty object?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

```ts
export interface MapObj {
  (s: string): TaskDaylist
}

let map: MapObj = {};
```

and I get a type error

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type '(s: string) => TaskDaylist'.
> Type '{}' provides no match for the signature '(s: string): TaskDaylist'.

I can't make it optional with `?`:

```ts
  (s: string)?: TaskDaylist
```

Is there another way that I can type the map and instantiate it with an empty object?

Comment: Are you aware that `MapObj` is defining a type for a function? It seems a remarkably bad choice of name for something that is neither a map nor an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) for that:

```
let map: MapObj = {} as MapObj;
```

Or simply:

```
let map = {} as MapObj;
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20TaskDaylist%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MapObj%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(s%3A%20string)%3A%20TaskDaylist%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20map%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20MapObj%3B))

---

#### Edit

The type you have for `MapObj` is a type for a function, so something like this:

```
let map: MapObj = function (s: string) {
    return {};
};
```

If you just want an object which maps between strings (key) to TaskDaylist (values), then it should look like this:

```
interface MapObj {
    [s: string]: TaskDaylist;
}
```

More about it in [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

Comment: thanks! that removes the error, but i'm loosing intellisense in vscode.

Comment: In what way? `map` should be of type `MapObj`. The question though is, why would you want to set an empty object to something that needs to be a function?

Comment: @NitzanTomer I think you should include that last comment as part of your answer. It seems most likely here that the OP thinks they're defining a type with string keys mapping to `TaskDaylist` values.